# How to view the tables in Excel that has header with merge cells in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, datasource, closedxml

I have code that I got from YT. It shows data in a datagridview with a regular Excel file.

If the Excel file has merged cells as its headers, it won't view the data in it.

In short, how can I view a table only that starts in row 15? Since the rows 1 to 14 were merged to be the Excel header.

Here is the code I used:

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", Multiselect = false })
{
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(ofd.FileName))
        {
            bool isFirstRow = true;
            var rows = workbook.Worksheet(1).RowsUsed();
            DataView dv = dgvVessels.DataSource as DataView;

            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                if (isFirstRow)
                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());

                    isFirstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;

                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i++] = cell.Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            dgvVessels.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            lblTotal.Text = $"Total Records: {dgvRecs.RowCount}";
        }
    }
}
```